# Rails can't find exception_notification gem even though I have it installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I recently installed the exception_notification plugin/gem (I'm confused as to whether it's properly install as a plugin or as a gem) and I'm getting this:

```
Could not find exception_notification-2.4.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

This is in spite of the fact that I already have that version of the gem installed:

```
$ gem list | grep exception_notification
exception_notification (2.5.2, 2.4.1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using a vendored bundle?

If so, it sounds like you just need to run

```
bundle install
```

In your rails directory. (Assuming you've already added that gem to your Gemspec).

http://gembundler.com/rails3.html

Comment: I've tried `bundle install`. Doesn't seem to affect the problem.

Comment: @JasonSwett, please edit your question and post the contents of your Gemfile. Without that, it's not easy to debug this problem.